# How to get file shared assets in Win 8.1 universal app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml

I have universal app and shared assets in it. These are pictures I use both in the mobile and in the desktop app. But, obviously installation folder is not accessible in code-behind. Is there way how to achieve that or I have to add pictures to both platform-wise projects?

Answer (score 0):

> But, obviously installation folder is not accessible in code-behind.

No, it is accessible.

> Is there way how to achieve that or I have to add pictures to both platform-wise projects?

We can use [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) to access the folders or files in the installed location for example like this:

```
var assetsfolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
```

And we don't need to add pictures to both platform projects. You can create a folder for example named "ShareAssets" in the [ProjectName].Shared like this:
[image]

And I put a image under this folder, so will both the windows 8.1 project and windows phone 8.1 project be able to access this folder:

```
<Image Source="ShareAssets/miao4.jpg" />
```

As the method I provided, we can also access this folder in the code behind from both platform:

```
var shareassetsfolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("ShareAssets");
```